# Sending coins when the priv/public keys are not in wallet (bitcoind)

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

I've created the hex for a raw transaction but do not have the wallet priv/keys in the wallet. Can I still send the transaction using sendrawtransaction? I've checked the message using signrawtransaction and this returns complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should not need the keys to be in the wallet to send a transaction using sendrawtransaction(). All sendrawtransaction() does is broadcast it over the network.

Comment: Thanks - although I read somewhere I have to use the -reindex flag. Which I've done.